# Magento 1.9.2.4 upgrade via downloader

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

We are upgrading Magento from 1.9.2.4 to Magento 1.9.3.4 through the downloader but downloader is not showing Upgrade Available.

Please find the screenshot [below](https://prnt.sc/fwnj5y):

[image]

Please help us on this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go To **downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php**

**Find line:**

```
$uriModified = $this->getModifiedUri($uri, $https);
```

**Before this line write:**

```
$https = false;
```

**Comment this line:**

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```